# A reference that is not to 'const' cannot be bound to a non-lvalue

Tags: c++, constants

Am struggling a bit with this.

Am declaring:

```
BYTE *pImage = NULL;
```

Used in call:

```
m_pMyInterface->GetImage(i, &imageSize, &pImage);
```

Visual C++ 2003 compiler error:

> error C2664: 'CJrvdInterface::GetImage' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'BYTE **__w64  ' to 'BYTE **&  '
>   A reference that is not to 'const' cannot be bound to a non-lvalue

The method called is defined as:

```
void CMyInterface::GetImage(const int &a_iTileId, ULONG *a_pulImageSize, 
                            BYTE** &a_ppbImage)
```

Any help much appreciated,
Bert

Answer (score 8):

Because GetImage can modify it's third parameter, you need to give it something to modify:

```
BYTE **ppImage = &pImage;
m_pMyInterface->GetImage(i, &imageSize, ppImage);
```

It is possible that after your function returns, that `&pImage` and `ppImage` may no longer be the same (which also means that `pImage` and `*ppImage` may be different).  If you add this:

```
if (ppImage)
    pImage = *ppImage;
```

after the call, you should be good.

If `CMyInterface::GetImage` is your own function, depending on what you do, you may be able to change it.  In your function, do you ever do:

```
a_ppbImage = ...;
```

or do you only write:

```
*a_ppbImage = ...;
```

If you only do that latter and not the former, passing a reference to a double pointer is overkill.  You can either pass a reference to a single pointer (`BYTE *&image`) or you can pass a double pointer (`BYTE **image`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify the variable 'pImage' inside the method 'GetImage()' you should either be passing a pointer or a reference to it (not doing both).

What you probably want is:

```
BYTE *pImage = NULL;
x.GetImage(iTileId, pulImageSize, a_pImage );
```

With the method defined as:

```
void CMyInterface::GetImage(int const& a_iTileId, ULONG* a_pulImageSize, BYTE*& a_ppbImage)
{
}
```

PS. Be consistent where you put your & and * in type declarations.

```
ULONG   *a_pulImageSize   // Star on the right
BYTE**   &a_ppbImage      // Star on the left (not consistent)
```

Personally (and this is just my style others are different) I put everything on the left (with the type) just the variable name goes on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You declared GetImage() to expect a reference to a Byte**.

```
void CMyInterface::GetImage(const int &a_iTileId, 
                            ULONG *a_pulImageSize,
                            BYTE** &a_ppbImage);
```

You passed it a reference to a Byte*.

```
BYTE *pImage = NULL;
m_pMyInterface->GetImage(i, &imageSize, &pImage);
```

To make your method call work as written, you need to change your definition of GetImage() to

```
void CMyInterface::GetImage(const int &a_iTileId, ULONG *a_pulImageSize,  
                            BYTE* &a_ppbImage)
```